# Passing dynamic string variables with special character to JQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I generated custom checkbox for select or unselect my data. I have 2 custom functions for selecting and unselecting data. In the select method i need to pass 2 variables and it is field value.

**My code:**

```
<span custom-checkbox="true"
is-checked="false"
name="id"
data-val="{this.id}"
on-select="DataSelect('{this.id+'\',\'' +this.name}')"
on-unselect="DataUnselect('{this.id}')" id="{this.id}">
</span>

function DataSelect(id, value){ 
  console.log(id);
  console.log(value);
  //my code
}

function DataUnselect(id, value){   
  //my code
}
```

**Issue:**

name field contains special characters like quotes (''). the following are the sample data;

```
id = "1";
name= "hey'len";
```

Here i got the issue due to the quote('). So data manipulated as ;

```
DataSelect('1', 'hey'len')
```

So i got as "*Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list*".

Please help me correct this

Comment: try this name.replace("\'"g,"\\'")

Comment: please help to update in the method itself. in html dataselect

Comment: Can you please provide little more info. Because it looks like that this can't be done with jquery alone (Processing of '{..}' in html)..

Comment: @domino_katrino thanks. I got it. but how i generalize like all the special characters or any encoding help it?

Comment: I hope answer from Jayesh Chitroda will help.

Comment: thanks that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape quotes from string using `.replace()`

```
id = "1";
name= "hey'len";
name.replace('\'', '\\\'');
```

Comment: hi, if multiple quotes in the name, it failed. Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
id = "1";
name= "hey'len";
name.replace('\''g, '\\\'');
```

Use this it will replace all occurance of ('). It also work fine with "hey'len'new'something".

Try It

Comment: I need this including multiple occurrence. but this is not working

Comment: @Akhil That's great

Answer (score 0):

If your replace string have special charaters you have to replace it before create RegExp like this:

```js
var html = `
<div>This is Html</div>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's m</div>
<p>asdasdasally unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets <span>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?w=100" />
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it </span>
to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
`;

var oldImage = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?w=100';
var newImage = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?w=1000';

var fixOldImageToRegExp = oldImage.replace(/\//g, '\\/').replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\w/g, '\\w');
var re = new RegExp(fixOldImageToRegExp,'gi');
document.write(html.replace(re, newImage));
```

and this is running [codepen](https://codepen.io/vndevil/pen/eYJBBZJ)